# SharePoint editprofile.aspx always redirects to /Person.aspx, even with mysites disabled

Tags: my-site, user-profile, 2007

I have a SharePoint farm in which I have modified the global action menu to include a link to `/_layouts/editprofile.aspx`.  This is fine as far as it goes, but when the user posts to this page, it always tries to redirect to `/Person.aspx`.  My site collection settings do not have a Portal provider connection enabled, and my mysite provider is also configured to disallow users from creating mysites.

I have tried using the `DefaultReturnURL` and `ReturnURL` properties of the `Microsoft.SharePoint.Portal.WebControls.ProfileEditor` control on the `editprofile.aspx` page, but to no avail.

Anyone have any suggestions?  This is a pretty annoying issue for users, but I'm a bit at a loss about what to do (short of configuring IIS to always redirect for /Person.aspx, which I'd rather not do).

Answer (score 1):

It is important to understand that person.aspx is separate from the actual MySite Site Collection(s).  It is part of the actual personalization host that can provision MySites if users have access.

Here are some details from an MSDN thread that may help:  http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/sharepointsocialcomputing/thread/d5009aa8-8cbf-4943-85ad-18490540eebc

The approach I would take is to deploy the MySite host so that the profile page can render.

Answer (score 1):

I've experienced it as well. AFAIK the problem was introduced somewhere around SP2. We solved it by creating a delegate control that always redirects to user to the correct page that replaced the OOB redirect delegate control.

Answer (score 1):

I've solved it by creating a very simple HTTPModule (took 15' to build it - you are constraint to deployment, so be sure you have access to web.config files on your WFEs) that forces the same redirect everytime that page is called. Actually there is a parameter in the query string, i believe is called something with "alwaysForce" that when put to FALSE it uses the reqular page and not the mySites page.

Hope it helps,
C. Marius

Comment: Isn't a HTTPModule an overkill for this (see solutions below). All request will always go through it, which can impact performance.